# Create zip file from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd, xp-cmdshell

Here is code which I use to create a `.rar` file with a password

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(1000),
        @destination VARCHAR(1000),
        @Command VARCHAR(1000)

SET @source = 'E:\Temp\testRar.txt'
SET @destination = 'E:\Temp\testRar.rar'

SET @Command = '"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"  a -ep1 -pasd^ad ' +@destination+' '+@source

EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @Command
```

but it sets `asdad` password and not `asd^ad`, `^` symbol is ignored. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ^ character is an escape character in the command shell. Try doubling it up.

```
SET @Command = '"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"  a -ep1 -pasd^^ad ' +@destination+' '+@source
```

Comment: `'"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"  a -ep1 -pasd"^"ad '` ?

Comment: After some research I find answer, double ^ should be used instead one, '"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -pasd^^ad '

Comment: how can create rar file without password?